# Classic ASP azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, asp-classic, cicd

The application technology is classic ASP. Can the azure CICD be setup for this classic ASP application?
If yes, then what are the tasks to be used in build and release pipelines for build,unit test,code analysis etc?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as Classic ASP doesn't need to be compiled, it is just a matter of bundling the pages, copying to the server and un-bundling and copying the pages to the appropriate folder.

So the build step would just be get latest (hopefully from source control) and zip it up.

Release would be to stop IIS, copy the package to the server, unzip it, and copy to the folder and start IIS.

I've not seen unit tests done with Classic ASP, you would need some automated test suite.